# How can I get travis to run npm test with a faucet command for a nodejs build

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

For my nodejs build. Travis automatically runs `npm run test` This produces a very large output, so for the CI build I want to run `npm run test | faucet`. I do not want to add this to my package.json as we want the log files and it is very helpful for new developers.

How can we get travis to run a custom npm test command?

Comment: You can [Custimize the `build` step](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Customizing-the-Build-Step), which seems like it's what you want